# Binary operations in js

Tags: javascript, binary, aes, bitwise-operators, rijndael

I've been trying to figure out how to implement some stuff about rijndael algorithm in js. One particular step (mixColumns) requires to mess around with binary numbers. I decided to follow a guide and at a particular point it does this operation:

it has to multiply `d4 (hexadecimal)` by `2`. Now `d4` in binary is `1101 0100`, and it's turned into `1010 1000`. I guess this is because he left-shifted the number so the leftmost number goes away and a 0 is pushed in the right side. After that it does `1010 1000 XOR 0001 1011` and then the result is: `1011 0011`
I don't understand where those XOR and `0001 1011` come from.
I tried to do `10101000 ^ 00011011`, yet I didn't manage to get the same result.
Could anyone explain me why that? Please try to be as clear as you can, since I'm new with binaries and these operations.

(Also, sorry for my english or imperfections (it's my first question here));

By the way, I'm also trying to understand this one:

```
{03} . {bf} = {10 XOR 01} . {1011 1111}
 = {1011 1111 . 10} XOR {1011 1111 . 01}
 = {1011 1111 . 10} XOR {1011 1111}
 = 0111 1110 XOR 0001 1011 XOR 1011 1111
 = 1101 1010 (ans)
```

It does more or less the same things, it converts the `bf` and the `3` in binary, then it becomes `10 XOR 01`..and then..I don't know..
still far away from the solution.

I also wonder if there is a simplest way to do what it does.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you understand the basic operation of `XOR`? The result has `1` wherever the bits in the two inputs are different, `0` when they're the same.

Comment: ok..maybe I'm stupid. I didn't think about the for loop, that's why I asked here what I could be missing, but I figured out I could reach his same result just doing a for loop and iterating over each value put in an array. I thought I would have worked if had done something like `binary1 ^ binary2` ..using the whole number, but I was wrong. So your comment reminded me the basics, thank you!.